How to delete the numbers between two delimiters?
I have some garbage data:
trueText = ' 23  Wolkenvelden en   lokaal wat regen. In  de ochtend op  steeds meer  plaatsen droog en  24 zon. In de avond   kans op onweer,met   name in Zeeland.   22      20 23   = max. temp.  vandaag   '

I want to delete the numbers that are between the  characters because this is useless. Sometimes there can be a number in the text so that's why I only want to delete those between the  characters.
I have tried some things myself:
trueText = re.sub('[^]+', ' ', trueText)

This deletes everything between the  characters. I think I have to use the \d sequence but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Can you show what the result should be exactly?

it should be trueText = '   Wolkenvelden en   lokaal wat regen. In  de ochtend op  steeds meer  plaatsen droog en   zon. In de avond   kans op onweer,met   name in Zeeland.             = max. temp.  vandaag   '

trueText = re.sub('[^]+', lambda x: ''.join(c for c in x.group() if not c.isdigit()), trueText)

"Sometimes there can be a number in the text", but your example does not have a number in the text. If trueText is ' foo 1 bar ', should the output be ' foo  bar ' or ' foo 1 bar '?

You can remove all digits in the match value using
trueText = re.sub('[^]+', lambda x: ''.join(c for c in x.group() if not c.isdigit()), trueText)

See the Python demo:
import re
trueText = ' 23  Wolkenvelden en   lokaal wat regen. In  de ochtend op  steeds meer  plaatsen droog en  24 zon. In de avond   kans op onweer,met   name in Zeeland.   22      20 23   = max. temp.  vandaag   '
print(re.sub('[^]+', lambda x: ''.join(c for c in x.group() if not c.isdigit()), trueText))

Output:
   Wolkenvelden en   lokaal wat regen. In  de ochtend op  steeds meer  plaatsen droog en   zon. In de avond   kans op onweer,met   name in Zeeland.             = max. temp.  vandaag   


Those "box" characters are not all the same. They have in common that they are in the range \uf000 and \uf100. To remove those together with any intermediate spaces or digits, you can do:
s = re.sub(r'[\uf000-\uffff]+([\s\d]+[\uf000-\uffff]+)*', '', trueText)
s = re.sub(r'(\s)\s+', r'\1', s)  # Remove double white space
print(s)

For the given example input, that would print:

Wolkenvelden en lokaal wat regen. In de ochtend op steeds meer plaatsen droog en zon. In de avond kans op onweer,met name in Zeeland. = max. temp. vandaag

You should however review the decision to remove all those numbers, as it seems that at least one of those numbers represents a temperature. Not sure you have the information needed to decide which numbers to keep and which to discard...

You could use re.sub('\s*[\d]\s*', ' ', trueText) too to remove every number that is in between 's (removing them as well), then replacing it with the same  characters - that is, if the data behind those non-printable characters is not needed.
